# Display the specfied list in frontend

Tags: reactjs

Goal:
Display the content of listGetAllIndustry in frontend.

Problem:

```
"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {listGetAllJobAdvertisement, listGetAllLocation, listGetAllIndustry}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
```

What part of the code am I missing in order to display the content of listGetAllLocation at frontend?

Info:
*I'm new in React JS

[image]
[image]
[image]
Thank you!

---

```
{"listGetAllJobAdvertisement":[],"listGetAllLocation":[{"locationId":1,"city":"LOS ANGELES","country":"USA"},{"locationId":2,"city":"LONDON","country":"ENGLAND"},{"locationId":3,"city":"BERLIN","country":"GERMANY"}],"listGetAllIndustry":[{"industryId":1,"name":"ENERGY"},{"industryId":2,"name":"MATERIALS"},{"industryId":3,"name":"INDUSTRIALS"},{"industryId":4,"name":"CONSUMER STAPLES"},{"industryId":5,"name":"HEALTH CARE"},{"industryId":6,"name":"FINANCIALS"},{"industryId":7,"name":"INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY"},{"industryId":8,"name":"COMMUNICATION SERVICES"},{"industryId":9,"name":"UTILITIES"},{"industryId":10,"name":"REAL ESTATE"}]}
```

---

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { VacantPositions } from '../../src/contexts/api';

class Open extends Component {
  state = { aaa: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
      fetch(VacantPositions)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ aaa: data }  ))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      { this.state.aaa}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Open;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this error since you are directly using state variable `aaa` in `render` function's return statement without telling react how to convert the `aaa` variable into JSX.

I have included `aaa` and and 1 more variable `bbb`. Depending upon what you want you can keep 1 variable remove the other one and its corresponding usage from your `Open` component.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Open extends Component {
  state = {
    // state variable should be object if api response is object
    aaa: {},
    // if you only store 'listGetAllIndustry' then state variable should be array
    bbb: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // I am assuming the api response to be this
    const data = {
      listGetAllJobAdvertisement: [],
      listGetAllLocation: [
        { locationId: 1, city: "LOS ANGELES", country: "USA" },
        { locationId: 2, city: "LONDON", country: "ENGLAND" },
        { locationId: 3, city: "BERLIN", country: "GERMANY" }
      ],
      listGetAllIndustry: [
        { industryId: 1, name: "ENERGY" },
        { industryId: 2, name: "MATERIALS" },
        { industryId: 3, name: "INDUSTRIALS" },
        { industryId: 4, name: "CONSUMER STAPLES" },
        { industryId: 5, name: "HEALTH CARE" },
        { industryId: 6, name: "FINANCIALS" },
        { industryId: 7, name: "INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY" },
        { industryId: 8, name: "COMMUNICATION SERVICES" },
        { industryId: 9, name: "UTILITIES" },
        { industryId: 10, name: "REAL ESTATE" }
      ]
    };
    // fetch(VacantPositions)
    // .then(results => results.json())
    // .then(data => this.setState({ aaa: data }  ))
    // .catch(err => console.log(err))

    this.setState({
      // keeping complete api response in the state
      aaa: data || {},
      // keeping only 'listGetAllIndustry' from api response in the state
      bbb: data.listGetAllIndustry || []
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.aaa.listGetAllIndustry &&
          this.state.aaa.listGetAllIndustry.map((industry) => {
            return (
              <div key={industry.industryId}>
                <span>{industry.industryId}.</span> &nbsp;
                <span>{industry.name}</span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        ===================================
        {this.state.bbb.map((industry) => {
          return (
            <div key={industry.industryId}>
              <span>{industry.industryId}.</span> &nbsp;
              <span>{industry.name}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Open;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your api is returning objects with multiple key and values you're setting that object into the state called 'aaa' , so you can't directly render a object in the return part you can render only particular value in the return method . You can use object.entries.map

```
{Object.keys(this.state.aaa).map(function(key, index) {
 return (
<p>{key}</p>
<p>{index}</p>
)
})};
```

or you can specify the particular value like

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
  { this?.state?.aaa?.listGetAllLocation[0]?.city}
  </div>
);}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

When I use "  { this?.state?.aaa?.listGetAllLocation[0]?.city}
" I get the error message
"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: { this?.state?.aaa?.listGetAllLocation?.[0]?.city} check this one ?

Comment: "{ this?.state?.aaa?.listGetAllLocation?.[0]?.city}" works and no error display in console.
No data is displaying in the frontend

Comment: I guess some formatting issue make a console and check whether aaa is array or object
 `render() {
return (
  <div>
  {console.log( this?.state?.aaa)}
  </div>
);}
 `

Comment: "return (   <div>   {console.log( this?.state?.aaa)}   </div> );}" don't show the data. Please take a look at the picture (content updated)

Comment: everything seems working not sure why try displaying other values in the object  like { this?.state?.aaa?.listGetAllIndustry[0]?.industryId}